# Debian Preseed use whole device for LVM Physical Volume

Tags: debian, lvm, preseed

I have the following recipe for a preseed install (truncated for readability):

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
  boot-root :: \
    1 1 1 free \
      $iflabel{ gpt } \
      $reusemethod{ } \
      method{ biosgrub } \
    . \
    512 512 1074 ext2 \
      $defaultignore{ } \
      method{ format } \
      format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } \
      filesystem{ ext2 } \
      mountpoint{ /boot } \
    . \
    2147 800 -1 $default_filesystem \
      $lvmok{ } \
      lvm_name { root } \
      method{ format } \
      format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } \
      $default_filesystem{ } \
      mountpoint{ / } \
    . \
    100% 512 100% linux-swap \
      $lvmok{ } \
      in_vg{ vg_01 } \
      method{ swap } \
      format{ } \
    . \
    100 10000 -1 $default_filesystem \
      $defaultignore{ } \
      method{ lvm } \
      device{ /dev/sdb } \
      vg_name{ vg_01 } \
    [...]
    .
```

This makes **almost** what I want, the only issue is that partman-auto creates the Physical Volume **inside** a partition of /dev/sdb (i.e `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`).

**What I really want** is partman-auto to create the PV on the **whole device** (i.e `pvcreate /dev/sdb`).

The reason why I want to do this is simple: easy online (hot) extend. (This is for a virtual environment).

I have tried multiple solutions but none of them seems to be working like removing the PV from my recipe and adding to my preseed file:

```
d-i partman/early_command \
  string dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1; pvcreate -ffy /dev/sdb; vgcreate -fy vg_01 /dev/sdb
```

But this make the installer either fail or hang asking me what partition layout I want.

Please help me if you know how to accomplish what I want or even if you know that it's impossible with preseed only at this time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that partman (Debian Installer tool for partitioning) supports that.

I've filed a wishlist in Debian bug tracker, it's currently marked as "wontfix":
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=418519

Answer (score 0):

Even before trying preseed configuration, in manual installation partman is not able to use an existing PV created first by `pvcreate /dev/sda` and go on with LV defitions.

For partman lack of partition table on main boot disk is a no-go situation.

Recent Linux kernel have fixed reboot requirement after partition table edition. So delete PV partition and create it again larger to match virtual disk size, and run `partprobe` to inform kernel about its new size to then invoke `pvresize /dev/sda1`: [How to extend a Linux PV partition online after virtual disk growth](https://serverfault.com/questions/378086/how-to-extend-a-linux-pv-partition-online-after-virtual-disk-growth)